# how to unpack little or big endian in Convert::IBM390

Tags: perl, ebcdic

I'm using [`Convert::IBM390`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Convert-IBM390/lib/Convert/IBM390.pm) to convert EBCDIC files to ASCII files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use Convert::IBM390 qw(:all);

open EBCDIC, "<D:/EBCDIC.txt" or die "error -> opening $!";
open ASCII, ">D:/ASCII.txt" or die "error -> opening $!";

my $text;
my $template = 'e15.0 e15 z4 I2 I2 i2 N16.0 p11.0';
binmode EBCDIC;
while (read (EBCDIC, $buffer, 67))
{
   @fields = unpackeb($template, $buffer);
   $text= join(",",@fields);
   print ASCII $text."\n";
}

close EBCDIC;
close ASCII;
```

I got this script in this [link](http://www.evanadowney.com/?cat=7)

I have problems when the EBCDIC data contain ***Little or Big Endian*** integers.

I had searched for unpacking those character and used [***N/n V/v***](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) but those things are not accepted in this module.
got error as

```
Invalid type in unpackeb: 'N'
```

The EBCDIC FILE from the mainframe consists of following columns:

```
EBCDIC Decimal(15,0)
EBCDIC String(15)
Zoned Decimal(4)
unsigned little endian integer(2)
unsigned big endian integer(2)
signed big endian integer(2)
big endian decimal(16,0)
packed decimal(11,0)
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you realise that *all* multi-byte binary numbers must be either little- or big-endian?

I assume it's an `i`/`I` or `s`/`S` field that you want to reverse the endianness of? It doesn't appear that `Convert::IBM390` will let you do that, but I'm not surprised as IBM System/360, System/370 and ESA/390 are all big-endian and you should never get any data that is little-endian. Where did your data come from?

My best suggestion is that you write a simple conversion routine that takes a 32-bit value and returns the same value with its endianness reversed. Here's a program that implements `swap_endianness_32` and demonstrates its functionality.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

printf "%08X\n", swap_endianness_32(0x12345678);

sub swap_endianness_32 {
    unpack 'N', pack 'V', shift;
}
```

**output**

```
78563412
```

Comment: my data file would be from mainframe system... will be having copy book based on that will update the `$template` . if i use some other value like `i / I or p/ P` it would allow but the values which got converted is not correct.

Comment: i have tried the same data with [`Convert::EBCDIC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Convert-EBCDIC/lib/Convert/EBCDIC.pm) the file got converted but other values which are not ebcdic are still present in convertedfile

Comment: @Borodin, Some machines have byte orderings that are neither little- nor big-endian. For example, I believe there's one that stores 32-bit numbers as 3412